# Django-tables2 renders same first and last row

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-tables2, django-1.10

I have a weird problem with `Django-tables2`. I've created a simple table with two columns - `timestamp` and `description`.

The problem is that the first object from `QuerySet` is not being rendered in the table. Instead of first object, there is last object copied in this row.

[image]

Now I'm populating this table with `Action` objects.

**MODEL**

```
class Action(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='actions')
    description = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{} - {} {}".format(self.user, self.timestamp, self.description)
```

**VIEW**

```
@decorators.is_authenticated_or_homepage
def dashboard(request):
    print Action.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    recent_actions_table = RecentActionsTable(Action.objects.filter(user=request.user))
    context = {'user': request.user,
               'recent_actions_table':recent_actions_table}
    return render(request, 'main_app/dashboard/index.html', context=context)
```

**TABLE**

```
class RecentActionsTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = Action
        fields = ('id','timestamp','description')
        attrs = {'id': 'id_recent_actions_table',
                 'class': 'table', }
```

As you can see, I've printed the queryset before creating a table:

```
    <QuerySet [<Action: futilestudio - 2016-12-29 16:15:33.299000 New product created (6)>, 
<Action: futilestudio - 2016-12-29 16:53:29.534000 Manual scan of product>,
 <Action: futilestudio - 2016-12-29 17:05:38.215000 Manual scan of product>,
 <Action: futilestudio - 2016-12-29 17:27:05.462000 New product created (7)>]>
```

The first object is not in the table. Instead, there is duplicated object with ID 5.

Do you have any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution for this problem but I don't know what had caused it.

I've just configured table to allow ordering:

```
@decorators.is_authenticated_or_homepage
def dashboard(request):
    user = request.user
    recent_actions_table = RecentActionsTable(Action.objects.filter(user=request.user))

    # >>>>>>>>>>>> ADDED THE LINE BELOW <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    RequestConfig(request).configure(recent_actions_table)

    context = {'user': user,
               'recent_actions_table':recent_actions_table}
    return render(request, 'main_app/dashboard/index.html', context=context)
```